# WP Query issue for multiple values

Tags: wp-query

I have a custom field with the key `colour` and the value can either be `red` or `blue` for individual posts.

I know the code to return posts that are either red or blue i.e. `?colour=red`, but I don't know the code to return posts that are either red or blue i.e. `?colour=red&colour=blue`.

I have received help with the code from a user, but still not working...any assistance is gratefully received...thanks

```
<form action ="" method="get">
    <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="colour" VALUE="red"> Red<BR>
    <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="colour" VALUE="blue"> Blue<BR>
    <button type="submit" name="">Search</button>
</form>

<?php
    if($_GET['colour'] && !empty ($_GET['colour'])) {
        $colours= $_GET['colour'];
    }

    $meta_query = array('relation' => 'OR');
    foreach ($colours as $colour) {
        $meta_query[] = array(
          'key'       => 'colour',
          'value'     => $colour,
          'compare'   => 'like',
        );
    }
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    while($query -> have_posts()) : $query -> the_post();
 ?>
```

Comment: I did a rollback on this question because the most recent edit rendered it unintelligible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `$args` but it isn't define.

IN your form, you need to add double bracket to make $colours an array.

```
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="colour[]" VALUE="red"> Red<BR>
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="colour[]" VALUE="blue"> Blue<BR>
```

$value){
        $colours[]=$value;
    }

```
$meta_query = array('relation' => 'OR');
foreach ($colours as $colour) {
    $meta_query[] = array(
      'key'       => 'colour',
      'value'     => $colour,
      'compare'   => 'like',
    );
}
$args = array('meta_query'=>$meta_query);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Still receiving the error invalid argument supplied for foreach()  <?php
if($_GET['colour'] && !empty ($_GET['colour']))
{
$colours= $_GET['colour'];
}
?>
<?php
$args = array('meta_query'=>$meta_query);
$meta_query = array('relation' => 'OR');
foreach ($colours as $colour) {
    $meta_query[] = array(
      'key'       => 'colour',
      'value'     => $colour,
      'compare'   => 'like',
    );
}

$query = new WP_Query($args);
while($query -> have_posts()) : $query -> the_post();
 ?>

Comment: $colours is not an array in your code. You need to loop through the get values.

Comment: I edit the answer,

Comment: Updated my code above, but now getting a 'syntax error, unexpected end of file'

Comment: Be carefull to correctly open and close php tags between HTML and php, i correct it. I'm with my smartphone, maybe there's some error with " ' ",

Comment: That works, bugged me for ages....cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass in an array in your `$_GET` parameter (which I think is what you're trying to accomplish), you can't do it like this:

```
example.com/?colour=red&colour=blue
```

That will result in `$_GET['colour']` being `blue`, since it's the last parameter.

Instead, craft your URL like this:

```
example.com/?colour[]=red&colour[]=blue
```

which should result in `$_GET['colour']` looking more like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => red
    [1] => blue
)
```

See [this Q&A on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833330/how-to-get-php-get-array) for more info.

#### Edited to add

That said, you should make sure you've got an `array` in the first place. You could do something like this:

```
if($_GET['colour'] && !empty ($_GET['colour'])) {
    $colours = (array) $_GET['colour'];
}
```

Also, you should **really** be [validating, sanitizing, and escaping user data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data). ***Never blindly trust user data.***